# create a request authentication with forms

Tags: laravel

I need to manage access to an account,in particular I want to create a form that asks the user credentials user and password already present in a db, and after
    authenticating them redirect me to the page of user,but I do not know how to handle authentication.

ROUTE:

```
Route::get('/registrazione/store2','RegistrazioniController@store2')->name('registrazione.store2');
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function store2(tabella_utenti $utente,Request $request)
{
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email);
    $utenteId=$utente->id;
    return redirect(route('utente.show',compact('utenteId')));

}
public function show(tabella_utenti $utente)
{
    return view('registrazione.utenteShow',compact('utente'));
}
```

VIEW:

```
<!--form accesso-->
<div style="display: none; margin-left: 550px" id="form2">
    <h2 style="color: red">Accedi</h2>

    {!! Form::open(['route'=>'registrazione.store2']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('email','Email',['style'=>'h3']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('email','',['class'=>'form-control','style'=>'width:220px','placeholder'=>'Inserisci@la mail']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('password','Password',['style'=>'h3']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('password','',['class'=>'form-control','style'=>'width:220px','placeholder'=>'inserisci la password' ]) !!}
    </div>
    {!! Form:: submit('accedi',['class'=>' btn btn-primary']) !!}
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{route('homepage')}}"> home </a>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use authentication in laravel.

Its better to use inbuilt functionality to handle authentication than to create it from scratch

use php artisan make:auth() to generate basic authentication in laravel

follow the documentation and then if you want you can customize it according to your needs.

docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.X/authentication (change 5.X to your laravel version)